# Forgotten BIOS admin password - HPprobook 450 G1

Tags: bios, passwords

I own an HP probook 450 G1 and unfortunately I have forgotten my BIOS admin password which I set about 1 month ago (I wrote it down somewhere but I cant find that location). How can I reset it - in order to be able access my BIOS settings? Thanks.
**NB** - I am using the - white background with blue colored text - HP login interface.

Answer (score 2):

Generally to reset the BIOS password (and much of the other system settings) all you need to do is to remove the RTC battery for a few minutes. It looks like a watch battery and should be clearly visible after you slide off the bottom cover. The [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03943639) has detailed instructions, if necessary.

Comment: Not successful, I am still prompted to enter my my BIOS admin password on the white HP login interface after I boot my machine and press F10. (I have removed the RTC battery for about 10mins)

Comment: @Juko Can you try following [this procedure](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03767649)?

Comment: I have followed the link and ended up on the HP support website, unfortunately I do not have the required validation info to access resources from the site.

Comment: I have used the cmospwd-5.0 tool and have managed to kill my BIOS password. On rebooting my machine to the BIOS settings I end up - and get stuck on the HP - white background - screen that reads:

**begin-screen**

The CMOS checksum is invalid. The CMOS will be set to the default configuration and will be rebooted. Please see your BIOS setup options to see if they change.,

CMOS reset (502),

ENTER - Reboot the system,

**end-screen**
The machine then automatically boots to windows after about 40secs. However it still prompts for a BIOS password when I reboot to BIOS. What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: ***Dear Customer,

 

Welcome to HP Support Forum and we are glad to assist you.

 

This is to inform you that all HP Business Notebooks such as Probooks or Elitebooks have more stringent security than consumer models infact they don't produce 'halt codes', the password cannot be derived from the Serial Number and the code is stored in non-volatile memory so removing the RTC cell will not reset the password in this case.

 

Please have a look at this link. 

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/49497-HP-​​Probook-Elitebook-BIOS-Password-Reset-Utility***

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the hard drive.
2. Reboot the computer and press F10 for BIOS setup.
3. Chose log in as Guest on the options that follow.
4. Reset the BIOS security options to default and save the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However I still get the white HP login screen asking me as the BIOS admin to enter my password. (I removed my hard drive and rebooted my laptop 1. Without the hard drive and 2. With the hard drive replaced). Same result. Frustrating...

Comment: *there is/was no "log in as Guest option"