# How to reset UEFI administration password on HP ProBook 450 G1 notebook?

Tags: bios, passwords, uefi, password-recovery, reset

I have a used HP ProBook 450 G1 notebook.

I want to reset the UEFI, format the disk and reinstall Windows.

Unfortunately, I do not know the password for the UEFI administration account. Therefore I can't boot from a USB drive to format the disk.

Is there a way to reset the UEFI administration password?

Comment: Does [HP Notebook PCs - Managing the Administrator Password in UEFI BIOS | HP® Customer Support](https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c04828407#:~:text=Changing%20the%20Administrator%20Password%20in%20UEFI%20BIOS,-Follow%20these%20steps&text=in%20UEFI%20BIOS.-,Turn%20on%20the%20computer%2C%20and%20then%20immediately%20press%20F10%20until,select%20Setup%20BIOS%20Administrator%20Password.&text=Type%20your%20new%20BIOS%20Administrator%20Password%2C%20and%20then%20press%20Enter.) answer your question?

Comment: As I read the HP article, you need to know the BIOS (UEFI) password to change it. Ask the prior owner for the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forgotten BIOS admin password - HPprobook 450 G1](https://superuser.com/questions/999941/forgotten-bios-admin-password-hpprobook-450-g1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a used HP ProBook 450 G1 notebook. ...  Unfortunately, I do not
> know the password for the UEFI administration account.

Unfortunately, BIOS and Disk Passwords on anything from ten years old or newer cannot be altered by users without the knowledge of the existing password.

Sometimes, manufacturers can change parts (BIOS Chip) and reset the password that way, but not often and to the best of my knowledge, not recently.

Accordingly you need to get the password from the person / outfit that sold you the laptop computer. If truly not available, there is nothing else you can do with regard to the password.

If the machine will start and run, you may be able to do a Windows Repair install.  Use the option to Keep Nothing.  That will delete Data, Profile and Apps but does not need the UEFI password to run the Repair.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Comment: I just talked to the HP support. They also said that it is not possible.